# Restrictint input strings in table contenteditable cells

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an html table with attribute `contenteditable` in its cells. 
The cells are defined like:

`<td contenteditable="true" class="product_class"></td>`

I also have an array in backend code c# which has a list of allowed strings in `contenteditable` cells. How do I restrict the input to these strings? I thought of having a dropdown inside cells but I am trying to avoid this option as it requires intensive changes in the code I am working on.

Comment: you may need to add a Javascript function to td change event to validate the content string

Comment: How javascript will access the array in backend c# code to get the allowed list?

Comment: Also how will js know user has completed his input to start validation? Thanks

Comment: you need to pull the array list to front end and store in some hidden field or js array for doing client side validations. Also, use suitable td cell event for validating input when user completed input.